# dynamically populate Dojox CheckedMultiselect

Tags: javascript, dojo

```
function populateMultiSelect(optionData){
    require([
      "dojox/form/CheckedMultiSelect",
      "dojo/dom", "dojo/_base/window", "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(CheckedMultiSelect, dom, win){

     var sel = dijit.byId('dynamic');

     var n = 0;
     for(var i in optionData){
         var c = win.doc.createElement('option');
         c.innerHTML = optionData[i];
         c.value = optionData[i];
         console.log(optionData[i]);
         sel.appendChild(c);
     }

     var myCheckedMultiSelect = new CheckedMultiSelect({
       name: 'dynamic',
       multiple: 'true'
       }, sel);

 });
}
```

I have this data in the optionsData

> Object {1: "QOS", 2: "ATM", 3: "Software", 4: "Other", 5: "IPv6", 6:
>   "Management", 7: "LAN", 8: "LAN", 9: "QOS", 10: "LAN", 11: "WAN", 12:
>   "Security", 13: "Security", 14: "LAN"}

Why isnt this working.

I am trying to populate this field dynamically from a json. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

The code you use to access your `<select>` element is not correct. `dijit.byId()` is used to get the widget object. But since you have not created the widget yet (at that time), you cannot access it.
What you should use is the following code:

```
dojo.byId('dynamic');
```

If this doesn't work, could you please add the HTML code of the element with ID `dynamic`?

**UPDATE**: You can also try to add them to the widget itself by using the following:

```
myCheckedMultiSelect.addOption(c);
```

This means you have to put the for-loop after your widget declaration, like this:

```
function populateMultiSelect(optionData){
    require([
      "dojox/form/CheckedMultiSelect",
      "dojo/dom", "dojo/_base/window", "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(CheckedMultiSelect, dom, win){

     var sel = dojo.byId('dynamic');

     var n = 0;

     var myCheckedMultiSelect = new CheckedMultiSelect({
       name: 'dynamic',
       multiple: 'true'
       }, sel);

     for(var i in optionData){
         var c = win.doc.createElement('option');
         c.innerHTML = optionData[i];
         c.value = optionData[i];
         console.log(optionData[i]);
         myCheckedMultiSelect.addOption(c);
     }

 });
}
```

I also made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QzgyA/) as a proof of concept.

Comment: This is the HTML i have used.
  <select id="dynamic">
      </select>

Comment: @user1999099 I updated my answer, this should work now (tested it out on JSFiddle).

Answer (score 0):

You should use an array.forEach like so

```
function populateMultiSelect(optionData){
require([
  "dojox/form/CheckedMultiSelect",
  "dojo/dom", "dojo/_base/window", "dojo/domReady!"
], function(CheckedMultiSelect, dom, win){

 var sel = dojo.byId('dynamic');

 var n = 0;

 var myCheckedMultiSelect = new CheckedMultiSelect({
   name: 'dynamic',
   multiple: 'true'
   }, sel);

 myCheckedMultiSelect.startup();

 array.forEach(optionData, function(optionData) {
     myCheckedMultiSelect._addOptionItem(optionData);
 });
```

});
}